# Unable to generate URL for a named route

Tags: php, symfony

I already installed symfony/assetic-bundle and added the following lines in app/resources/views/admin/layout.html.twig :

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{  parent() }}

    {% stylesheets
    '@SonataTranslationBundle/Resources/public/css/sonata-translation.css'
    %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

But when I execute my project I have the following exception :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_assetic_e5b9ef4_0" as
>   such route does not exist.") in admin\layout.html.twig at line 9.

Comment: clear your cache, install assets, and assetic dump